# Unable to share a child folder while sharing from the parent in windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, network-shares, file-sharing

There are several child folders in parent folder on windows 8.

Times ago I shared some child folders and accessed them from from other devices without problems. Then I removed all child folders shares and instead shared their parent folder.

During the parent folder sharing the window appeared listing some of the previous child shares and asking "some of the folders were previously shared. you can replace their current settings with the same setting you just applied to the folder you shared".

If I click change settings after processing for a while it ends up with "folder can not be shared".

Despite the message the parent share folder is present in shares list and is accessible. However those few shares listed before and some others are not.

There are no such windows with "previously shared folders message" displayed if I share from computer management or from command line, but the same problem persist.

Answer (score 1):

In sharing a folder in Windows 7 or 8, you need to have proper permissions in both the sharing tab and the Security tab of the folder being shared.  Right click on your shared folder and make sure all the proper user settings are set on both tabs.

Also, click on Advanced button in the security tab of the main (root) shared folder and make sure the checkbox "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" is checked off for the user(s) you set the share for.